# Database Deleted after try EF Update

Tags: database, entity-framework

I need your opinion cause I'm having an issue in my EF application.

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Other Properties

    [Required]
    [Display("Name")]
    public string Property {get; set;}

    // Other Properties
}
```

And my DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
        public MyDbContextDbContext(String connectionString)
            : base(connectionString) {
        }
        public MyDbContext(DbConnection connection)
            : base(connection, false) {
        }
        public MyDbContext()
            : base("name=ConnectionString") {
        }

        public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses {get; set;}
}
```

My Migrations Configuration has this:

```
public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }
```

Now, when I run for the first time, everythings works fine, but let's say I change something in my class, let's say, not required...

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Other Properties

    //[Required]
    [Display("Name")]
    public string Property {get; set;}

    // Other Properties
}
```

This is my connection string:

```
data source=server.com\SQL2012;initial catalog=testdb;integrated security=False;user id=testuser;password=****;multipleactiveresultsets=True
```

I get this...
"CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'"

AND my Database is deleted from my hosting account...

Any ideas how to get through this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the connection string `ConnectionString`.

Comment: I must say that every time this happens I forgot to run update-database command. Is this the problem?

Comment: Quite possibly, I can't say so for certain.  Anytime you make a change to your data model the changes need to be migrated to the db.  If they're out of sync, it may attempt to run the db initializer.  Lots of people starting out with EF forget about `update-database`, unfortunately.

Comment: Isn't there and option to add to program.cs to do it automatically?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% on that.